# wxpython : wrap button label

Tags: python, wxpython

I am developing a wxPython GUI application where I need to create a Button label of big string - like "Change the Address"

The issue is that the button label does not gets wrapped and button size expands which is not the intention.

Is there any way we can wrap the button label around the button which is of specified size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't make buttons with long labels to begin with. Buttons are not supposed to have long labels. Use a TextCtrl or a StaticText instead.

However, if you really, really want to do this, try inserting line breaks into your strings. In Python, you would do this:

```
label= "Change the\n Address"
```

This works on Windows anyway with wxPython 2.9